# Get bigger size textarea inside popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to increase the size of my text box inside js

**HTML**

```
<button 
    class="button button-balanced ion-checkmark-round" 
    ng-click="reject()"
    style="margin-left:20%"></button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.reject = function() {
   console.log("Rejected function");  
   var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                template: '<input type="textarea" ng-model="data.wifi">',
                title: 'Rejected',
                subTitle: 'Description',
                scope: $scope,
                buttons: 
                    [
                        { text: 'Cancel' },
                        {
                            text: '<b>Save</b>',
                            type: 'button-positive',
                            onTap: function(e) 
                            {
                              if (!$scope.data.wifi) {
                                //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
                                e.preventDefault();
                                } 
                                    else {
                                            return $scope.data.wifi;
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                    ]
              });
```

is there any possibility to increase the size of text box or using text area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace the following code

```
<input type="textarea" ng-model="data.wifi">
```

By

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.wifi" style="width:100%" />
```

This should create a text box of 100% width. IF you want a text area, use:

```
<textarea style="width:100%" ng-model="data.wifi"></textarea>
```

Comment: err msg  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Please make sure you are using single quotes. or better to alert the value before setting the same. for example: using wither all double quotes or single quotes.

Comment: use this <input type="text" ng-model="data.wifi" style="width:100%" />   or <textarea style="width:100%" ng-model="data.wifi"></textarea> as per your requirement

Comment: Edited the original answer. Please review and confirm if the error still persists